# How to convert this syntax Swift into Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sorting

I'm converting a Swift project into Objective-C. And when I convert follow code, I don't know it's correct or wrong.

Swift

```
let closest = layoutAttributes.sorted {
    abs($0.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) < abs($1.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin)
}.first ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
```

Objective-C

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *closest = [[layoutAttributes sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    return
        fabsf([(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)a center].x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin)
        <
        fabsf([(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)b center].x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin);
}] firstObject];
```

Comment: What is the issue with your approach? I.e. what is the question?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me, but the proof is in the testing. Does it compile? Does it do what you expect it to do at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code a bit. Also the return value has to be different in Obj-C.

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *closest = [[layoutAttributes sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *a, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *b) {
    CGFloat distanceA = ABS(a.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin);
    CGFloat distanceB = ABS(b.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin);

    if (distanceA < distanceB) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (distanceA > distanceB) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    return NSOrderedSame;
}] firstObject];
```

The Swift `?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()` would be translated as `?: [[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes alloc] init];` but you don't need that there if your array is not empty.

Comment: Hear hear. That code is a hellova lot easier to read. The Swift version could use a similar cleanup pass.

Comment: @DuncanC In Obj-C it's not obvious that you can change the parameter types in the block signature.

Comment: Sulthan, that's true. That's something I always found helpful in dealing with Objective-C blocks. It enables you to avoid tons of typecasting in the body of the block. Plus your version expands the code to mulitple lines and uses temporary variables. That aids in both readability and ease of debugging, and a modern optimizing compiler strips out the temporary variables anyway. (Voted.)